# How to create and deploy image of Windows Mobile device?

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a Windows Mobile handheld device on which I installed several applications and libraries and set all settings and configuration options (like network, etc) to the correct values for the application(s).

Now I need to do the same to multiple other handheld devices. Is there a way to create an imagine of one device and load that image onto the other devices?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - create a cab file that does all the registry changes and deploys the files to the right paths.

If your changes only include registry changes you can use [mdsoft registry editor](http://ceregeditor.mdsoft.pl/) along with ActiveSync. It has an import and an export option, but it still means that you have to connect one device at a time to your desktop (ActiveSync limitation).

I am not familiar with an automatic way to detect files that were newly added, but with the registry you will find the option with the registry editor in case you have a "clean" device to compare with. The editor also provides you a cab wizard for the registry if I am not mistaken.